# iOS splash screen options for Cordova?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have to set the duration of a splash screen. In Android this is quite simple:

(android)config.xml:

```
<preference name="SplasScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
```

SplashScreen: value = splashscreen name in the res/drawable directory. It's recommended to have one name (screen.png) for all types of resolution. 
SplashScreenDelay: value = delay in ms (2s)

I have no idea how this could be applied to iOS. At the moment I have set all splashScreens which are loaded at the app-start. After that I have a white screen with a spinner before my app-content is displayed.

This is my standard xml-setting:
(iOS)config.xml:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value=".25" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
```

If I set ShowSplashScreenSpinner to false, the spinner doesn't appear. Updates to the rest of the settings don't take any effects.

Does anyone know what to do to show a splashScreen in iOS for a optional time?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it a bit differently like this:

#### First set:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

So it will not hide the splashscreen automatically.

#### Second:

In your `index.html` do this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 2000);
}
```

This will hide the splashscreen 2 seconds after the `onDeviceReady` event.
Instead of `2000` milliseconds you can set whatever you want. This setting should work for both `Android` and `iOS`.

Comment: Applying this changes the duration of the screen with the spinner. The spinner-background is transparent. Before the spinner-screen gets loaded, the splash-screen I set in the p-list is shown for a random duration.

Comment: I guess I need to set the splash-screen images somehow to the configuration of cordova.

Comment: try removing `FadeSplashScreen` and `FadeSplashScreenDuration` from config

Comment: It should be possible to set a reference to the ios splash screens, but they are all named different.

Comment: you set them in the `info.plist` file

Comment: I did, I mean a reference for Cordova

Answer (score 0):

in config.xml update

```
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="800" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

So it will not hide the splashscreen time and whitescreen automatically.